# How to remove the storage connection string from the footer in HangFire

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dashboard, hangfire

I am using HangFire for background tasks and I have integrated it into one of my ASP.net core MVC applications, but I would like to hide the connection string that shows in the footer of the dashboard. I have made some research on their documentation website but didn't find anything related.
HangFire version 1.7.31
Please advise.
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can change it from `DashboardOptions`:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    DisplayStorageConnectionString = false
});
```